# MPU 6050 accelerometer sends 16bit unsigned values

Tags: teensy, mpu6050

I'm using the GY-521 breakout board to get it's accelerometer data on a teensy 3.6. From what I understand, I should expect signed (so positive and negative) values from it, but instead I get values from 0 to 65535.

So here is what I get:

When the sensor lays flat on the table, my Z-Axis reads around the expected 16384. When I rotate the sensor in any direction up until 90 degrees, the value goes down to 0. Once I turn more than 90°, the value jumps up to around 65500, and when I continue rotating it goes down to around 50000 once the sensor is upside down (so 180°).

So it seems to me that for the first half of the rotation, I get the expected values, but then instead of getting negative values after dropping to zero, it jumps to the maximum value of an unsigned 16bit.

For the X and Y-axis, I get a similar result, but rotated 90 degrees.
So when the sensor is flat on the table, both axis read 0. When I turn the sensor in one direction, the value goes up to 16384 at 90°, and then back down to 0 after 180°. If I turn the sensor in the other direction, the value jumps up to around 65500, then goes down to 50000 at 90°, and then back up to 65500 at 180°.

Here is the entire code I use:

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int MPU = 0x68; // MPU6050 I2C address
float AccX, AccY, AccZ;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU); 
  Wire.write(0x6B); 
  Wire.write(0b00000000); 
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000);
  Wire.write(0x1C);
  Wire.write(0b00000001);
  Wire.endTransmission();      
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x3B); 
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU, 6, true);
  AccX = (Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read()); 
  AccY = (Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read()); 
  AccZ = (Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read()); 

  Serial.print(AccX);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(AccY);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(AccZ);
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: How can unsigned values be both positive and negative?

Comment: Oops, looks like I mixed up signed and unsigned a few times, thanks for pointing that out, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution that works for me.

I had to define the variables AccX, AccY and AccZ as "int16_t". This gives
me the expected signed values through the Wire function.

It's a bit of a workaround since I want to scale these values to decimal numbers, so I need to create another set of variables wich I define as float.

If anyone could explain why I have to define the variables this way or better yet has a nicer solution to the problem, I would be happy to hear it.

For now, I can work with what I've got.